# Looking for a command to use when using notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Say I have 1000 lines and they were all like this but with different numbers and letters:

```
ABCD 1234 - White, White
```

but the end of them all had the same `- White, White`.

How can I make all the lines so they were like this:

```
White ABCD 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ can use regular expressions in it's search and replace feature. Search for

```
^(.*) - White, White$
```

and replace it with

```
White \1
```

Make sure you check the "regular expression" radio button at the bottom of the dialog.

(Assuming that whyt you  say is true and they really all got the "White, White" at the end. If that could also be different colors tell me, this can be modified to work with it, too)

SHould look like this (using Notepad++ 6.5.2):
[image: Replace Dialog the way it should look]

Comment: Hi, yes they all end with white, like this:

Whirlpool AWE6517 Washing Machine - White, White"
Miele W1914 Washing Machine - White, White"
AEG L87480FL Washing Machine - White, White"
Beko WM74155LW Washing Machine - White, White"

I would want them to become:

White Whirlpool AWE6517 Washing Machine"
White Miele W1914 Washing Machine"
White AEG L87480FL Washing Machine"
White Beko WM74155LW Washing Machine"

I cant seem to do it with what you said, unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Providing you a creenshot of how to set it. I just tested it, it worked. Give me a minute ;)

Comment: @user3269882 there you go.

Comment: Hmm, yes my setup is the exact replica of yours. But does not seem to function at all when I go to replace. 

When I did it the top file got White at start, but still had - White. White at end, the rest were all same apart from bottom one which removed the White at end?

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Strange, worked fine for me in the exact example I was screenshotting. got `WHITE Whirlpool AWE6517 Washing Machine | 
WHITE Miele W1914 Washing Machine | 
WHITE AEG L87480FL Washing Machine | 
WHITE Beko WM74155LW Washing Machine` (replace | by a newline)

Comment: It's very strange. When I do exactly what you do, and then click replace all, I get message at bottom saying, 1 occurence was replaced.

and then they look like this:

White Miele W3164 Edition 111 Washing Machine - White, White"
Hoover DYN8144D1X Washing Machine - White, White"
Samsung ecobubble WF80F5E5U4W Washing Machine - White, White"
Indesit IWD61451 Washing Machine - White, White"
Hoover DYN9144D3X Washing Machine

For some reason bottom one loses the - white, white, top one gets white at start and same thing at end, and rest all the same.

Comment: The regexp only does 1 line at a time - use "repace all". still, that you're still getting the "white, white" at the end even at the occurance that was cahgend is rather strange.

Comment: I got it working now, thanks very much for all your help, I restarted notepad++ and that must have made a difference. Excellent, really appreciate ;)

Comment: Oh, wait. NOtepad++ does seem to parse the whole thing as one line for you. You really got the whitespace in between, do you? if so, make sure the "`.` matches newline" is unticked.

Comment: One last question if you don't mind, what would you do in the situation where the line was like this:

Miele W3164 Edition 111 Washing Machine - White, White"

and I wanted to keep the " at the end so it would become

White Miele W3164 Edition 111 Washing Machine"

Comment: If it's not always a " but any character: `^(.*) - White, White(.)$` -> `White \1\2`. If it's always a " there is an easier solution: `^(.*) - White, White"$` -> `White \1"`

Comment: That's amazing, once again thanks for all your help. I have spent hours manually doing these changes in the past, you have just saved me a heap of time ;) Have a great week.

Comment: Regexps are a very handy tool, every programmer as well as everybody working with huge amount of data should know them IMHO. There are pretty good tutorials, if you plan on learning it yourself. Best reference I know is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can just

1. go to the top of your document
2. hit `ctrl-H`
3. place `- White, White` in `Find what:` and leave `Replace with:` empty
4. click `Replace All` (search mode is normal, direction is down)

There is no need to use regex here.